# Sitecore Content Editor Exception : Data at the root level is invalid

Tags: sitecore-client

I am facing an issue when opening content editor :

> Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException Message: Exception of
> type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. Source:
> System.Web    at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)    at
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    at
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at
> System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
> Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Message:
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Source:
> mscorlib    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target,
> Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
> Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
> invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method,
> Object[] parameters, Object obj)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs
> e)    at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()    at
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
> includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Xml.XmlException Message: Data at the root level is
> invalid. Line 1, position 1. Source: System.Xml    at
> System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)    at
> System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()    at
> System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()    at
> System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
> at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options)
> at Sitecore.Data.Fields.PagePreviewField.ParseValue(String value)
> at Sitecore.Data.Fields.PagePreviewField..ctor(Field innerField)    at
> Sitecore.ApplicationCenter.PagePreview.PagePreviewManager.GetPreviews(Item
> item)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.ContentEditor.PagePreviews.GetHeader(CommandContext
> context, String header)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.FillParamsFromCommand(CommandContext
> commandContext, RibbonCommandParams ribbonCommandParams)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.GetCommandParameters(Item
> controlItem, CommandContext commandContext)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderLargeButton(HtmlTextWriter
> output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderButton(HtmlTextWriter
> output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter
> output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter
> output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean
> isContextual, String id)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter
> output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean
> isContextual)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunks(HtmlTextWriter
> output, Item strip, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean
> isContextual)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter
> output, Item ribbon, Boolean isContextual, ListString
> visibleStripList)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter
> output, Item defaultRibbon, Item contextualRibbon, ListString
> visibleStripList)    at
> Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.Render(HtmlTextWriter
> output)    at
> System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
> ControlAdapter adapter)    at
> Sitecore.Web.HtmlUtil.RenderControl(Control ctl)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.UpdateRibbon(Item
> folder, Boolean isCurrentItemChanged, Boolean showEditor)    at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.Update()
> at
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnPreRendered(EventArgs
> e)

I am not sure which XML is causing this issue so I don't know how to troubleshoot this.

Any help?

Comment: Something to do with preview. Sitecore.Data.Fields.PagePreviewField.ParseValue(String value)

Comment: Do you know which item you are on when the error occurs? As Mark said, it seems to be happening as you attempt to load the preview, which would usually indicate an issue in the XML for the layout

Comment: this error happens after i click content editor from launchpad directly, so i don't know which item is selected by default

Comment: By default Sitecore will select the default home item. Try to open the dbbrowser page from http://youdmomain/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx. Once from the dbbrowser, see what data and fields are being displayed for the home item.

Answer (score 0):

To track this kind of error down when you have no idea which Item is causing it I normally restore my Sitecore database locally and patch in my own custom type to be able to debug it. If you can't restore your DB locally maybe just add some logging and debug in you dev environment instead.

So to do this create a copy of the PagePreviewField in your codebase from Sitecore.Kernel (I used dotpeek to get this from Sitecore 8.2 Update 6):

```
 public class CustomPagePreviewField : CustomField
 {

     public PagePreviewField(Field innerField) : base(innerField)
     {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) innerField, nameof (innerField));
      this.xmlValue = this.ParseValue(this.Value);
     }


     public PagePreviewField(Field innerField, string runtimeValue) : base(innerField, runtimeValue)
     {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) innerField, nameof (innerField));
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) runtimeValue, nameof (runtimeValue));
      //log the field value here or attach debugger...
      this.xmlValue = this.ParseValue(this.Value);
     }

     ///the rest of the code from the ootb implementation goes here...

     private XDocument ParseValue(string value)
     {
         //log the field value here or attach debugger...
         Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) value, nameof (value));
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
           return XDocument.Parse("<p/>");
         return XDocument.Parse(value);
     }
 }
```

Then update the Sitecore config by patching in your custom field to replace the existing one, it should look similar to below once patched in:

```
<fieldType name="Page Preview" type="MyCustom.Extensions.Fields.CustomPagePreviewField, MyCustom.Extensions"/>
```

That should give you the item details you need to debug this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access items from DbBrowser (/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx). It rows raw values here without rendering. So you can check if any field values got problem and correct here.

If some field value starting with whitespace, content editor throws such error. So look out for that too.